# Exception Value: no such column: noticia_tb.id

Tags: python, django, sqlite, scrapy

I made a scraping application using scrapy, to scrape the news from a page, I put it to create a sqlite database, and then I made a django api to consume this database and make a link available in json, however when I upload the application from the following error:

> OperationalError at /news/
> no such column: noticia_tb.id

So I opened the database file and noticed that the ID was not generated, how do I generate this ID or use it without?

**follow my moldels.py**

```
class NoticiaTb(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    subtitulo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'noticia_tb'
```

**follow the scrapy project pipeline**

```
class ApinoticiaPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("myapinoticia.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS noticia_tb""")        
        self.conn.execute("""create table noticia_tb(
       
    title text, 
    subtitulo text,
    url text,
    data text,
    image_url text
)""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)       
        return item
    
    def store_db(self, item):    
        self.curr.execute("""insert into noticia_tb values (?,?,?,?,?)""",(str(item['title'][0]),str(item['subtitulo'][0]),str(item['url'][0]),str(item['data'][0]),str(item['image_url'][0])))              
        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: I don't understand, the `id` field is always generated by default by Django if you don't specify a column yourself which is the primary key. Are you sure you have run `makemigrations` properly?

Comment: I do have, the thing is that the database is n generated by django and yes by scrapy, I put it to django to use this existing database